# Unable to connect to a Linux Samba server via hostname on Windows 10

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, dns, samba

I have setup a Samba server running on CentOS. I am able to connect to it when typing `\\ip-address\share` into the address bar of Windows Explorer but it doesn't appear in the network list and if I try to connect to it using the hostname it tells me `Windows cannot access \\hostname\share`.

I also cannot ping the hostname but can ping the IP. I can ping the hostname from the CentOS

The Samba server has DHCP enabled (using NetworkManager) and the hostname is configured on the router via a static IP rule. hostname is also set via hostnamectl.

I have winbind is enabled and running, but have no idea if it is configured properly.

Firewall-cmd is active and running, and it has samba services open in the public zone.

I have updated seLinux with `sudo setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on`

Here is a partial dump of the smb.conf file;

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    netbios name = *hidden*
    wins support = Yes
    encrypt passwords = true
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = Yes
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    browseable = Yes

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
    write list = @printadmin root
    force group = @printadmin
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
```

How do I make it so windows is able to access the share via hostname?

EDIT: adding nmcli dump

```
connection.id:                          MyEth
connection.uuid:                        4b4c8ef6-def8-3c7f-9c1c-e3bdd39d2ed4
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.interface-name:              --
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        -999
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1565104013
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          no
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             B8:27:EB:FF:F8:7D
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   --
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:        --
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:            --
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             default
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       ""
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

firewall config:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client http samba https
  ports: 22/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: I disabled SMB1 and enabled SMB direct. lost a bunch of shares that were working fine before. I undid the change they came back, im not going to do that. This implys that those devices are running SMB1, which proves SMB1 is working fine.

Comment: Since you mentioned you're not able to ping the hostname but can ping the IP, I'd say there's no DNS entry for this server on your DNS Server. Test editing the hosts file on your Windows 10 just to find it out. The file path is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. If it works afterward, your solution should be add a real DNS entry for the host on the DNS Server.

Comment: @Ronaldo The DNS Server is a linksys router, I have followed all of the steps to create a DNS entry, I even deleted it and remade it. no sucess. Additionally, I have other linux and mac machines on the network, all of them are able to ping the hostname just fine. I think the DNS entry is fine, but with limited access to the configuration of the router (ie i am only able to access the web-gui) I don't think there is much I can do to confirm.

Comment: @JW0914 I am willing to take that risk. I don't have the time to reconfigure 90% of the devices on my network to drop SMB1.

Comment: @glend Your DNS settings on your router are not the issue

Comment: @JW0914 I agree, but SMB1 servers on my network are working fine because disabling SMB1 on windows creates about 4 other problems..

Comment: @JW0914 those devices which broke when turning off SMB1 were propriarty devices, I probably am unable to configure those servers. However, I do not have `/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf`. I can try to upgrade the centos samba server, should i force the version the global settings in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` using those directives?

Comment: @JW0914 I connected to the samba server using its ip on windows and performed a `smbstatus` the protocol version being used by windows is SMB3_11. Setting min/max versions is not the solution here. I don't think the reason is the samba server, rather how windows addresses linux hostnames.

Comment: Please post your _full_ samba server and client configs in a code box, anonymizing share names and IPs.  If you have CLI access to your router, please also post your Network, DHCP, DNS, and Firewall configs, as well as your Samba server logs _(anonymizing any applicable info)_

Comment: @JW0914 I have edited the OP. sorry, I do not know where the samba server logs are (ill see if i can find them). The client is windows 10 and as far as i can tell the only config options you have are the workgroup, and it matches. I do not know how to get access to the router config files, its a linksys router.

Comment: @JW0914 I think i found the logs (/var/log/samba) but there is nothing interesting in them except for the service starting and clients connecting. no errors.

Comment: @glend Please see my reply to your comment on my answer. You're running an unsupported share configuration by having SMB1 as the protocol, of which is no longer supported by any manufacturer or software developer. Its currently only still available for backward compatibility with ancient systems businesses may rely on, but Microsoft has clearly stated it is not to be enabled or utilized, which is why it was auto-disabled in either v1709 or shortly thereafter. Please take the time to fix the configuration, moving it to >SMB2 & your issue will be resolved by following the steps in my answer.

Comment: Also, verify what ports your firewall is classifying as `samba`, as the ports listed in the answer are required for what you're trying to accomplish, and it's possible `samba` may apply to only one or two of the ports, not the 5 (`tcp:139:445` & `udp:137-139`) that need to be set _(unless this is on a LAN with all traffic allowed)_.  I've also removed most of my comments to shrink this section

Comment: @JW0914 Mine wasn't disabled automatically and is enabling other systems to work. im not turning it off. i have opened the ports manually. restarted the samba machine. still doesn't work.

Comment: @glend There is only one solution to your issue and it's been stated, so either you deal with it or update your configuration... either way, my patience with talking in circles has expired.  You know the solution, so it's up to you what you want to do, either way, I'm done with this conversation.  Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is local DNS related and breaks down in the following way:

- *A more in-depth discussion in the FreeNAS Forum thread: [SMB shares not showing in network browsing](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/smb-shares-not-showing-in-network-browsing.54698/)*

  1. Local Domain must be set in the Router and echoed across all LAN devices ([#23](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/smb-shares-not-showing-in-network-browsing.54698/page-2#post-432096))

     - In Windows, this would be the WorkGroup name
  2. Static IP and Hostname must be set in the Router for the Samba Server ([#30](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/smb-shares-not-showing-in-network-browsing.54698/page-2#post-432202))
  3. Windows' `hosts` file must have an entry in it for the Samba Server ([#27](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/smb-shares-not-showing-in-network-browsing.54698/page-2#post-432147))

     - Format *(see #6 below)*: `IP  Hostname  Hostname.LocalDomain`
  4. Traffic must be allowed on the correct TCP & UDP ports ([#27](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/smb-shares-not-showing-in-network-browsing.54698/page-2#post-432147))

#### To Resolve:

---

1. Ensure the Windows device, Samba Server, and Router serving *local DNS* are set to the same Local Domain

   1. **Router:** Local Domain will be the name set under *Domain* in its WebAdmin UI
   2. **Samba Server:** Will depend on the OS
   3. **Windows:** Local Domain is the Workgroup name:

      1. `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` > *`Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings`*
      2. **Change settings** > **Change...** > **Workgroup** > **OK**

         - *Depending on the OS configuration, it may need to be rebooted*
2. Ensure traffic between Windows and the Samba Server is allowed on the following ports:

   1. **TCP:** 139, 445
   2. **UDP:** 137, 138, 139
3. Ensure Samba Server has been assigned a static IP on the Router

   ```ini
     IP      '192.168.1.2'
     mac     'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF'
     name    'Server'
   ```

   - *Without a static IP, which is where you set the client hostname & client MAC, configured in your Router, the Router has no idea on how to route traffic to the local DNS hostname.*
   - *Reboot Router once changed to allow for new DHCP pull by Server*
4. Windows 10 v1709 or greater, ensure *SMB Direct* is enabled and *SMB v1.0* is disabled

   1. `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` > *`Turn Windows features on or off`*
   2. **Uncheck:** SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support

      - *SMB 1.0 is not secure and has been actively exploited for >2yrs on devices with SMB v1.0 enabled*
      - *There is no reason to utilize SMB1, as all devices support at least SMB2*
   3. **Check:** SMB Direct
   4. **OK** *(Follow on-screen instructions and Reboot)*
5. Ensure Samba Server's `smb.conf` contains the following:

   ```ini
   [global]
       server min protocol  = SMB2
       server max protocol  = SMB3_11
       netbios name         = <Samba Server Hostname>
       workgroup            = <Local Domain>
   ```

   - Ensure `workgroup` Local Domain matches what was set in 1.3.2 *(above)*
   - Ensure `server max protocol` is the max of what *your* Samba Server build supports
   - Restart Samba to apply changes
6. Add Samba Server to Windows' hosts file

   - `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

     ```ini
     #

              ##::[[---  Windows Host Config  ---]]::##

     #===========================================================
                         ##----- LAN -----##
     #===========================================================

       # OpenWrt:
         192.168.1.1        OpenWrt   OpenWrt.Wrt
         192.168.1.2        Server    Server.Wrt
         192.168.1.3        Win10     Win10.Wrt
     ```

     - **1st Column:** Static IP of host
     - **2nd Column:** Hostname of host
     - **3rd Column:** Hostname and Local Domain address, where `Wrt` is the Local Domain
7. Open **This PC**, navigating to the share in the Address Bar: **`\\ServerHostname\ShareName`**

#### Troubleshooting:

---

If this does not resolve your issue:

1. Power-off the Windows device, Samba Server, and Router

   - *Simplest way to ensure DHCP is cleared*
2. Power-on Router and wait for it to fully boot up *(if OEM firmware: wait 120s || all others: 60s)*
3. Power-on Samba Server and Windows device

---

*Please post a comment if this doesn't work, allowing the answer to be tweaked, or added to, ensuring it works for all with this issue.*

Comment: Samba ports are open on both machines as they can communicate with each other, just not by hostname. static ip's have been assigned. they are in the same workgroup. windows is able to address other machines on the network using SMB1 only. editing the host file is not a solution, as the problem will persist on other clients.

Comment: @glend What steps did you not perform?  Might I suggest actually performing the steps required before deciding to simply dismiss them?  There are no other ways to solve the local DNS domain issue you're having with Windows 10, so it's up to you whether you want to actually fix your issue or stick with hubris.  Best of luck to you =]

Comment: I did 1,2,3 before posting my question. 4 breaks other devices on my network, because i tried it. 6 just isn't a reasonable solution.

Comment: @glend Turning off SMB1 on Windows 10 should not break other clients, unless you have shares on Win10 those clients are trying to access. In that case, consult Microsoft Docs for how to correctly set up those clients for SMB2. I cannot stress enough how enormous the security risk is of leaving SMB1 enabled, of which can only remain enabled after v1709 if the user goes in and manually re-enables it, as Microsoft auto disabled it in either v1709 or v1803.  You're essentially running an unsupported share configuration... please take the time to fix the configuration & your issue will be resolved.

Comment: I’m confused by steps 3 and 6 here.  When setting up a network with entirely Windows machines, you don’t need to mess with router settings, given anything a static IP address, or mess with a Windows hosts file.  Why are these steps necessary here; isnʼt that what netbios is for?

Comment: @DanielH OP's question wasn't about a Samba server running on Windows, but even if that was the case, the router still needs to know how to route the traffic by hostname _(please see first bullet under #3)_, the Windows client still needs to know how to identify the server by host name [#6] and be configured with the same `localdomain` [#1], and the Samba server still needs to be configured with the `localdomain` [#5]. Unless all three machines [file server (#5), router (#3), and client (#1, #6)] are configured as listed, routing via hostname won't work correctly _(issue the OP had)_.

Comment: My point is that it seems like these steps should not be necessary.  I found this because Iʼm trying to set up a Linux smb server to be accessed by a Windows client.  If the server were also Windows, then they could figure it out automatically *without* me messing with the router or hosts file; somehow, they would know what the hostnames mean *without changing those manually*.  It should be possible to get that to happen if the server is Linux too.

Comment: @DanielH The steps provided in this answer is the only way to get routing to correctly work when routing by `hostname` - if all three machines aren't configured with the same `.localdomain` _(Workgroup name in Windows)_, routing by hostname won't work since there's no way for traffic to be routed if all machines aren't on the same `.localdomain`, as the router has no way to know how to route that unless configured for it _(this is why static entries on the router and `hosts` file are required)_. Windows machines come defaulted with `.workgroup` as the local domain, routers usually have `.lan`

Comment: @DanielH For example, say the following local domains are configured: (1) `sambaserver.lan` (2) `router.lan` (3) `windows.workgroup` | Client [`windows.workgroup`] tries to access File Server [`sambaserver.lan`] via the Router [`router.lan`] - how is `router.lan` going to know where to route the request from `windows.workgroup`, when `router.lan` has no knowledge of local domain `.workgroup` and no routing table for it? Lets say that problem didn't exist, how is `sambaserver.lan` going to know how to process or send back data to `windows.workgroup` _(it'll try to send back to `windows.lan`)_?

Comment: @JW0914 I donʼt know.  My vague impression is “NETBIOS solves this” but that might be within a single domain/workgroup or something, and I know approximately no details of how it works.  But Iʼd think the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line would help with that.

Comment: @DanielH You have "no idea how this works" and think "NETBIOS solves this" - perhaps I could suggest doing some research and if you find some information within this answer is factually inaccurate, please let me know. SuperUser is an _answer_ site, not an opinion site or forum.

Comment: My question: why are these steps necessary in this case when they are not in the largely similar case of an all-Windows network, especially when the other (much less detailed) answer to this question is what I previously thought.  Yoo have anrwered that question with questions of how any alternative might work.  I don’t know what causes the alternative to work but it empirically *does*.  Having done further research, I think you might be using “by hostname” in a more technical sense than I am and I believe the original question asker was, to mean DNS name specifically not any resolvable name.

Comment: Also, when I said “I don’t know”, that wasn’t accurate.  I don’t know how NETBIOS works.  I do know of various ways it *could* work, which would allow the resolution of human-readable names to IP addresses without the router knowing the routes in advance.  I know some of them are used by other, similar systems.  I shouldn’t need to know the details of how it works under the hood to point out that several steps you list are unneeded in similar scenarios and to ask way this scenario is different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found that the nmb service is the solution.

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/nmbd.8.html